# PHP constant() referencing another class's constant

Tags: php

Within a class of mine I have a variable that contains a constant that is declared in another library class I'm using.

I am attempting to use it as such:

`constant($colour)`

Where `$colour = PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOUR_YELLOW`

PHP logs are throwing errors such as:

> PHP Warning:  constant(): Couldn't find constant
>   PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOUR_YELLOW

If I were straight up use the constant instead of a variable it'd work fine.
`PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOUR_YELLOW`

Any reason why I would be seeing this error using the `constant()` function with a variable?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it within a namespace, you'll need an absolute namespace.

`$colour = 'PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOUR_YELLOW'` is relative.

If `PHPExcel_Style_Color` is the top level namespace for that, then you probably just need to add a slash `\` at the beginning of it.

Try this:

```
constant('\' . $colour);
```

which will make the overall path:

```
\PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOUR_YELLOW
```

Without the slash, it's equivalent to:

```
MyNamespace\PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOUR_YELLOW
```

Comment: I'm guessing he's using a string, based on the error produced. OP's class might be namespaced. I believe the constant() function, like all other PHP functions that accept class names as strings, requires a fully qualified class name

Comment: Yes it's a string.
I apologize on being dense, but what should I do differently to fully-quality the class name?

Comment: If it isn't within another namespace, generally just adding a slash before it will do the trick.